# Using a Queue to pass data between two BackgroundWorkers

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, queue, backgroundworker

I'm reading and decoding a binary file, byte by byte. For that, I use two `BackgroundWorker`s : one for reading the file, that produces a `List<byte>` of variable size for each "line" of my file, and one for handling the "lines".

Since I want them to run in parralel and I can't know which one will be faster than the other, I use a `Queue` to pass data between the two `BackgroundWorker`s.

Here's the thing : none of the `List<byte>` should contain any `0` value, at any moment. I check that *before* adding them to the Queue. Still, at the other end of the `Queue`, some lists contain `0` values. Yet, i create a new `List<byte>` at each call of `Dequeue()`, since apparently, if I don't, the data is modified before the handling is finished.

I've tried to manually create a new `List<byte>` object and *then* assigning it the result of `Dequeue()`, without improvements. this is my first time working with a `Queue`, and since my code is multithreaded, it's nearly impossible to debug step-by-step.

```cs
Queue<List<byte>> q = new Queue<List<byte>>(); // My FIFO queue

// Reading thread
private void BackgroudWorkerRead_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
      // ... read the file
      List<byte> line_list = new List<byte>();
      // ... filling line_list with data
      // in this part I check that no byte added to line_list has the value 0, or else I display an errror message and end the process
      q.Enqueue(line_list);
      if (!backgroundWorkerNewLine.IsBusy) backgroundWorkerNewLine.RunWorkerAsync(); // if the other BackgroundWorker isn't processing data, now it needs to since we just added some to the queue
}

// Processing thread
private void backgroundWorkerNewLine_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    while (q.Count > 0) // While there is data to process
    {
          string line_str = DecodeBytes(new List<byte>(q.Dequeue())); // Decoding
          string[] elements = line_str.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.None); // Separating values

          Form1.ActiveForm.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(() => AddRow(elements))); // Add the line to a DataTable from the main thread
    }
}

public string DecodeBytes(List<byte> line)
{
 /// ... read each byte and return a string of the whole decoded line
}

public void AddRow(string[] el)
{
    MyDataTable.Rows.Add(el);
}
```

It seems that the List returned by q.Dequeue() doesn't return the same data that was added by q.Enqueue()

Comment: Reading and writing at the same time on two different threads is gonna give you a bad time.

Comment: Use [`ConcurrentQueue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentqueue-1?view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 0):

You should use Microsoft's Reactive Framework (aka Rx) - NuGet `System.Reactive.Windows.Forms` (assuming you're writing a WinForms app) and add `using System.Reactive.Linq;`.

Rx let's you use the familiar LINQ syntax to work with parallel operations.

You haven't shown us how you are breaking a file down into a list of `List<byte>`, so I'm going to assume you have a method that looks like `IObservable<List<byte>> DeconstructFile(FileInfo fileInfo)`.

Now you can do this:

```
IObservable<string[]> query =
    from bytes in DeconstructFile(new FileInfo("myFile.bin"))
    from line_str in Observable.Start(() => DecodeBytes(bytes))
    select line_str.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.None);

IDisposable subscription =
    query
        .ObserveOn(Form1.ActiveForm)
        .Subscribe(el => MyDataTable.Rows.Add(el));
```

That's it. It runs in parallel, with the `Observable.Start` starting new threads as needed, and automatically passes on the results to each step. The  `.ObserveOn(Form1.ActiveForm)` automatically marshalls the `.Subscribe` to the UI thread.

If you need to stop the code before it is complete just call `subscription.Dispose()`. Simple.

Answer (score 0):

When you create multithreaded applications you must be very careful to prevent different threads from accessing shared resources at the same time. If you don't prevent it, bad things happen. You are losing updates, your data structures become corrupted, and all these are happening unpredictably and inconsistently. To avoid these problems you are supposed to synchronize all access to shared resources from different threads. Which can be achieved by using the [`lock`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/lock-statement) statement. So the advice is: always lock when you are reading **and** updating shared resources. The shared resource in your case is the `Queue`. You should lock like this:

```
// Reading thread
lock (q)
{
    q.Enqueue(line_list);
}

// Processing thread
while (true)
{
    List<byte> list;
    lock (q)
    {
        if (q.Count == 0) break;
        list = new List<byte>(q.Dequeue());
    }
    string line_str = DecodeBytes(list); // Decoding
    // ...
```

The downside of locking is that it creates contention, so you should not lock more than absolutely necessary. Especially avoid doing heavy computations while holding a lock.

Beyond that, the pattern you are trying to implement is the producer-consumer pattern, and .NET offers a specialized class to facilitate this pattern. It is the [`BlockingCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.blockingcollection-1) class, and it handles all this messy thread synchronization for you. It can help you reduce the code you have to write, at the cost of a small learning curve. You basically need to learn the methods `Add`, `CompleteAdding`, and `GetConsumingEnumerable`, and you are ready to go.